# How to change iPhone/iPad app to iPhone only?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I've been a bit stupid and built my app as being targeted for both iPhone and iPad, whereas it should really just be for the iPhone.

How do I change the settings so that the build is only for the iPhone? I've actually finished coding the app and ready to submit it, so hopefully it's just a case of changing some obscure project settings (as opposed to creating a new project and coping all the code over).

Thanks St.Ov.!

Comment: How can you do this programmatically via Targeted Device Family build setting?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to change the `Targeted device family`. Select the project, then `info-->Deployment--->Targeted device family` to `iPhone` only and you have to do the same thing in targets. After that your app will be only for iPhone.

Good Luck!

Comment: +1 React native created my project as iPhone-only by default, so I had to do the reverse to change it to Universal.

Comment: I actually realize building my app with iPhone-only by default.. will still be able to support iPad after I launch my app on App Store. I tried downloading using iPad via App Store, everything works fine.

Answer (score 20):

U can do this by going through the following steps.

1. Select Edit Project settings from Projects .
2. Go to build settings.
3. Select Targeted Device Family and Choose iPhone.

That should do it.

Have fun.

Comment: In my case "Targeted Device Family" allows me to select 1, 2, or 1 and 2. 

1 is iPhone
2 is iPad.

Comment: As of current XCode 12 (2020), this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

For Xcode 5.1.1:

Select your project and then go to:

General->Deployment Info -> Devices

and then select just iPhone

Comment: Good. Apparently Apple cannot resist the need to completely re-write the workflow at every major version. None of these answers work for Xcode 6 :( ! (Edit: oh well, actually it did... just took me some time to realize this wasn't a menu)

Answer (score 3):

In XCode 9.4.1

1. Project Navigator -> Select Project
2. General -> Deployment Info
3. Devices -> iPhone

Answer (score 2):

1. Project -> Edit Project Settings -> Build -> Targeted Device Family = iPhone
2. Open "[project]-Info.plist" and change "Main nib file base name (iPad)" in "MainWindow_iPhone"

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 4.2:

1. Select the project navigator (little folder icon in the top left), then select your project (the top most item)
2. Move across to the next column, select the appropriate target
3. Move across to the next column, select the summary tab
4. Select iphone from the devices dropdown.