# React Native: Unwanted Black border on ipad 2 simulation

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am testing a new (simple) reactive native app, choosing ipad 2 as target in the simulator.

The loading screen shows full screen, but the first application screen (by react native) shows a big black border around the content. I created a completely new project, but it has the same border.

Is this a known issue? Do I need to add something  to prevent this border from happening?

EDIT: I have an impression the application is built as an iphone app, but deployed/displayed to an ipad. I see the 1x / 2x button. Probably this is causing it. So probably the first question is: how do I configure xcode that it is actually an ipad app?

Thanks in advance!

Jeroen

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The application was being built as an iphone app, but deployed/displayed to an ipad. I see the 1x / 2x button. This was causing it. So: how do I configure xcode that it is actually an ipad app? See url below:

[How to change iPhone/iPad app to iPhone only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104157/how-to-change-iphone-ipad-app-to-iphone-only)

Comment: Yes, I added the solution in case anyone else ran into the same problem. Unfortunately you cannot accept your own answer until a few days later (48h).

Answer (score 72):

Go to **Build Settings**
Type **Targeted Device Family** in search bar
Select **1,2**

Run the project it should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 10):

Now with newer version of XCode. **Build Settings** -> **Targeted Device Family** -> Select **Universal**.

Answer (score 7):

I had this issues and solved it with this way,

1. Go to XCode, and General tab
2. In App Icons and Launch Image sections,

   2.1. Click the dropdown Launch Image Source, and a pop up 
   will come out, click Migrate

   2.2. Click the dropdown Launch Screen File, and select the very first one
3. Go to Build Settings Type Targeted Device Family in search bar Select 1,2

I had this issues after updating assets for AppIcons and SplashScreen

Hope it helps!

Comment: This works perfectly, As you have mentioned I got the issue after setting up SplashScreen and AppIcons, Thanks!